# How to convert a list of strings into a numeric numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

I want to be able to calculate the mean, min and max of `A`:

```
 import numpy as np

 A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']

 NA = np.asarray(A)

 AVG = np.mean(NA, axis=0)

 print AVG
```

This does not work, unless converted to:

```
A = [33.33, 33.33, 33.33, 33.37]
```

Is it possible to perform this conversion automatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you want [astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

```
NA = NA.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 10):

You had a list of strings

You created an array of strings

You needed an array of floats for post processing; so when you create your array specify data type and it will convert strings to floats upon creation

```
import numpy as np

#list of strings
A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']
print A

#numpy of strings
arr = np.array(A)
print arr

#numpy of float32's
arr = np.array(A, dtype=np.float32)
print arr

#post process
print np.mean(arr), np.max(arr), np.min(arr)

>>>
['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']
['33.33' '33.33' '33.33' '33.37']
[ 33.33000183  33.33000183  33.33000183  33.36999893]
33.34 33.37 33.33
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']
# convert to float
arr = np.array(map(float, A)) 
# calc values
print np.mean(arr), np.max(arr), np.min(arr)
```

Output:
`33.34 33.37 33.33`

Comment: Just a note: this will not work in Python 3 because `map` doesn't return a list.

Answer (score 1):

`A = [float(v) for v in ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']]`

or

`A = np.array(['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37'], dtype=float)`

Answer (score 1):

To convert your strings to floats, the simplest way is a list comprehension:

```
A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']
floats = [float(e) for e in A]
```

Now you can convert to an array:

```
array_A = np.array(floats)
```

The rest is probably known to you:

```
mean, min, max = np.mean(array_A), np.min(array_A), np.max(array_A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import numpy as np

A = ["33.33", "33.33", "33.33", "33.37"]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    n = A[i]
    n=float(n)
    A[i] = n

NA = np.asarray(A)

AVG = np.mean(NA, axis=0)
maxx = max(A)
minn = min(A)

print (AVG)
print (maxx)
print (minn)
```

Hope this helps!!!
Basically, you didn't have the functions for min and max and your strings in the list had to be integers

Comment: What if the list could not be changed and you had to leave it as strings?  Try not to make assumptions.

Comment: This does not work, as you are not converting the values, but not putting them in a list!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) which can even deal with list of multi-line text containing numbers:

```
import numpy
A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']
NA = numpy.loadtxt(A)
B = ['33.33 33.33\n', '33.33 33.37\n']
NB = numpy.loadtxt(B)
```